# Removing 'wget' removed the Chrome also. Why?

Tags: apt

I installed 'axel' to download the things from internet. So I thought of removing the 'wget'. But when I did the same using command

```
#sudo apt-get remove wget
```

It removed google chrome as well. Why this happened?

```
rana@Brahma:~$ sudo apt-get remove wget
[sudo] password for rana: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for rana: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfolks-telepathy25 libpurple0 telepathy-salut libfolks-eds25 gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libindicate-gtk3 libnspr4-0d
  telepathy-indicator nautilus-sendto-empathy libmission-control-plugins0 libfolks25 folks-common libnice10 libgssdp-1.0-3
  telepathy-haze libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 libavahi-gobject0 libtelepathy-logger2 libtelepathy-farstream2 telepathy-mission-control-5
  telepathy-logger telepathy-gabble gstreamer0.10-nice libgupnp-1.0-4 libpurple-bin libmeanwhile1 libzephyr4 libfarstream-0.1-0
  libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 empathy-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  curl
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  flashplugin-installer foomatic-db-engine google-chrome-stable hplip printer-driver-postscript-hp ubuntu-standard wget
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 7 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 161 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main curl i386 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.6 [137 kB]
Fetched 137 kB in 2s (54.1 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 216983 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing flashplugin-installer ...
Removing foomatic-db-engine ...
Removing google-chrome-stable ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode.
Removing printer-driver-postscript-hp ...
Removing hplip ...
Removing ubuntu-standard ...
Removing wget ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common ...
Processing triggers for cups ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
(Reading database ... 216722 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking curl (from .../curl_7.22.0-3ubuntu4.6_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up curl (7.22.0-3ubuntu4.6) ...
```

And here's the output of `aptitude why google-chorme-stable wget`:

```
rana@Brahma:~$ aptitude why google-chrome-stable wget
p   google-chrome-stable Depends wget
```

Comment: That is really strange, it shouldn't have done that as far as I know...

Comment: Couldn't it be that there are other packages processing for other previous commands? If so `apt-get autoremove && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` should deal with it. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Braiam - Here is the output of the command you asked for. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6606466/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the reason is simple:

`google-chrome-stable` **Depends** of `wget`. If wget is not installed Google Chrome will be uninstalled too since Chrome can't work without wget (apparently).

Comment: @Alvar See the edited answer: `rana@Brahma:~$ aptitude why google-chrome-stable wget` -->
`google-chrome-stable Depends wget`

Comment: @braiam - How can we know such thing ( which thing depend on what) beforehand so that we can take care in future?

Comment: @Anurag when you removed wget it told you that will remove Chrome: `The following packages will be REMOVED: (sip) google-chrome-stable`, you didn't read what was removed actually, hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-cache depends google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable
  PreDepends: dpkg
  Depends: ca-certificates
  Depends: fonts-liberation
  Depends: libasound2
  Depends: libatk-bridge2.0-0
  Depends: libatk1.0-0
  Depends: libatspi2.0-0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcairo2
  Depends: libcups2
 |Depends: libcurl3-gnutls
 |Depends: libcurl3-nss
 |Depends: libcurl4
  Depends: <libcurl3>
  Depends: libdbus-1-3
  Depends: libdrm2
  Depends: libexpat1
  Depends: libgbm1
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
 |Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: <libgtk-4-1>
  Depends: libnspr4
  Depends: libnss3
  Depends: libpango-1.0-0
  Depends: libwayland-client0
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxcb1
  Depends: libxcomposite1
  Depends: libxdamage1
  Depends: libxext6
  Depends: libxfixes3
  Depends: libxkbcommon0
  Depends: libxrandr2
  Depends: wget
  Depends: xdg-utils
  Recommends: libu2f-udev
  Recommends: libvulkan1
```

if wget is to be removed/purged,google-chrome-stable will be also be removed as expected.